# How to execute perf (linux tools) on android device?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, perf

I followed the following steps and succesfully compiled using the make command in 3rd step. But am unable locate perf as mentioned in step 4.

Steps:-
1) `export NDK_TOOLCHAIN=${NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-`

2) `export NDK_SYSROOT=${NDK}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm`

3) `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${NDK_TOOLCHAIN} CFLAGS="--sysroot=${NDK_SYSROOT}"`

4) `adb push perf /data/perf`

> Error:
>   cannot stat 'perf': No such file or directory

How to locate perf after cross compiling it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would help with your way of building the tool,
but I compiled it using AOSP source build system, the tool (available in external/linux-tools-perf) after compilation was placed in
$OUT/system/bin
It should be in some ./bin folder as its a native executable